# How to use variable name or array value as name to initialize another array?

Tags: arrays, perl

My array will have strings as below...

```
my @array1 = ( "CE_2N_Comp_ChmProcess",
             "CE_2N_Comp_FmMasterProcess"....
             "CE_2N_Comp_EmaProcess" );
```

And I want to use array1 values as name of new arrays... e.g.,

```
my @CE_2N_Comp_ChmProcess = (1,2,3);
my @CE_2N_Comp_FmMasterProcess = (4,5,6);
.
.
my @CE_2N_Comp_EmaProcess = (7,8,9);
```

Please help.

Expected array names

```
my @CE_2N_Comp_ChmProcess = (1,2,3);
my @CE_2N_Comp_FmMasterProcess = (4,5,6);
.
.
my @CE_2N_Comp_EmaProcess = (7,8,9);
```

Comment: Can you share what you have done to get the desired output

Comment: This is a bad idea in many ways. Don't do it. Perl has perfectly good data structures. You can access things by name using a hash. Don't use the variable namespace as if it was a hash.

Comment: Re "*And I want to use array1 values as name of new arrays*", [No, you don't](https://perl.plover.com/varvarname.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [`reply`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Reply) (Perl console), using a `HASH` with `ARRAY`s *data structure*:

```
> my $h = {} # create a HASH ref
$res[1] = {}

> push @{ $h->{CE_2N_Comp_ChmProcess} }, (1,2,3);
$res[2] = 3

> push @{ $h->{CE_2N_Comp_FmMasterProcess} }, (4,5,6);
$res[3] = 3

> push @{ $h->{CE_2N_Comp_EmaProcess} }, (7,8,9);
$res[4] = 3

> use Data::Dumper;
> print Dumper $h
{
  'CE_2N_Comp_ChmProcess' => [
                               1,
                               2,
                               3
                             ],
  'CE_2N_Comp_EmaProcess' => [
                               7,
                               8,
                               9
                             ],
  'CE_2N_Comp_FmMasterProcess' => [
                                    4,
                                    5,
                                    6
                                  ]
}
```

Or used dynamically :

```
0> my $h = {}
$res[0] = {}

1> my $c = 0;
$res[1] = 0

2> for ("CE_2N_Comp_ChmProcess", "CE_2N_Comp_FmMasterProcess", "CE_2N_Comp_EmaProcess") { \
    push @{ $h->{$_} }, (++$c .. ($c+2)); $c+=2 }
$res[2] = ''

3> use Data::Dumper;
4> print Dumper $h;
{
  'CE_2N_Comp_ChmProcess' => [
                               1,
                               2,
                               3
                             ],
  'CE_2N_Comp_EmaProcess' => [
                               7,
                               8,
                               9
                             ],
  'CE_2N_Comp_FmMasterProcess' => [
                                    4,
                                    5,
                                    6
                                  ]
}
```

Comment: But the problem is I never know the Array (Hash key name in your case) name, it is dynamically received from remote end.

Below array values (CE_2N_Comp.... etc) are dynamically received... I want to name these values as new array names
my @array1 = ( "CE_2N_Comp_ChmProcess",
             "CE_2N_Comp_FmMasterProcess"....
             "CE_2N_Comp_EmaProcess" );

Comment: So edit your question to better explain what the input looks like, how it's formated, where the list comes from and how to map them